# Athena JDBC output format

Tags: amazon-athena

When you execute a query in Athena, the results are generally available in `CSV` format. I am looking for other possible output formats like `TSV` or other, because one of my column has `CSV` value already.

MY data

```
A a,b,c 123
B a,b 123
```

When I give the following query:

```
select * from table ;
```

I get the result in csv like

```
"""A""","""a","b","c" , 123
```

I need it to be TSV. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the Athena console only does CSV, as you discovered.  But you can use the [Athena JDBC driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) to run the query from another program, like [SQL Workbench/J](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html#use-ate-with-sql-workbench).

Comment: actually when i run a query using JDBC driver the results are generated in  the same s3 folder where my input data is . the format of the data is always csv. I would like to use some other delimiter for my own use. I guess you are getting the picture

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and Amazon support confirmed that Amazon Athena's results are available only in CSV format.